# Releasing memory when ViewDidDisappear in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, memory

I would like to release memory in arrays with photos when transitioning from a viewController. I have tried autoreleasepool like the following, but it does not work. Will you teach me how to release memory? Thanks.

```
   autoreleasepool{
        imageArray = []
    }
```

Comment: Swift uses **Automatic Reference Counting (ARC)** under the hood, so there is no need to manually release your memory.

Comment: Why did you think that the memory was not getting released ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object will only be retained if another object has a strong reference to it. As soon as your view controller disappears, it will most likely be deallocated as well, which automatically removes its strong references to other objects. Thus, if `imageArray` is strongly referenced only by your disappearing view controller, the memory will automatically be released. You do not need to use an `autoreleasepool`.